# can i run more than one program inside a bluemix python application?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

Is there a way to run more than one python program inside a bluemix application?

I see that Procfile in the example has web: python server.py

I tried adding a similar line to Procfile for my second program, but that does not seem to be the syntax

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes - you can start any number or (almost) any type of processes. For example, assuming you have, say foo.py, in the same directory as server.py, you should be able to specify in your Procfile something like:

web: python foo.py & python server.py

That should start foo.py in the background and run server.py in the foreground.

However, don't expect CF to restart your container if the foo.py script crashes (as CF would if server.py did). That's something you would have to worry about.

Another way to start a process with your app is via using the .profile.d scripts: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/deployingapps.html#customize_dep